# Is it acceptable to include multiple keys in JSON object

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I want to create a JSON object that would fit into several "types". For example, I have a vehicle category of sedan that fits into three types- family vehicle, work vehicle and recreational vehicle. Is it acceptable to have three "type" in the same object? Is this a bad practice? If yes, then how else can I represent all three (or more types)

```
{
"category":"sedan",
"name":"Ford",
"type":"workVehicle",
"type":"familyVehicle",
"type":"recreationalVehicle"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, all keys must be unique in JSON and BSON objects, so the typical approach would be to use an array field in this case:

```
{
  "category": "sedan",
  "name": "Ford",
  "type": ["workVehicle", "familyVehicle", "recreationalVehicle"]
}
```

Comment: Worth adding that...not only is it 'bad practice' to have multiple keys of the same name, it's also '**not going to work**' in 99.99% of JSON libraries. Because the behaviour in this situation is not specified, most libraries would either take the first value, or the last, while a few may error out.